# How to add background image in laravel 9

Tags: css, laravel, frameworks, background-image, laravel-9

I am trying to add a background image for my website in Laravel 9.51.

I've used this in my css file:

```
body {
background-image: url("background.jpg");
}
```

But it doesn't work. Also tried:

```
body {
background-image: url({{asset('background.jpg')}});
}
```

but it doesn't work either. Any ideas? My background picture is stored in public folder.
Btw,
I can access it from my browser on route:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/background.jpg

Comment: Are you using Vite or Laravel Mix? What error are you getting in the browser console? Are you linking the CSS file to your webpage?

Comment: Css is linked (tried with other styles and it works fine). Browser doesn't show any errors but doesn't display the picture. Inspection doesn't show I've added picture :( Sorry not sure if it is Vite or Laravel Mix, any help how to chek it?

Comment: You can check your `package.json` in the root directory to check the bundler you are using. Further, I would suggest is create a reproducible repository on Github or similar app, so we can have more context of what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Sanskar, I'm using Vite 0.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine this is the folders structure:

- Resources

  - images

    - your_image.png
  - css

    - style.css

First of all, don't forget to do `npm run build` or `npm run dev`.

Write the relative path to the image from your css (no quotes needed). In this example:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../images/your_image.png);
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this one**

```
background: url("background.jpg") center center no-repeat;
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, it's basically the same solution I've already tried :(

Answer (score 0):

```
body {

    background:url('url-photo-background');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I' having no problems to add picture off internet. Any ideas how to add it locally?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the photo with the address of the photo that is in the local

```
body {
    background: url("/images/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Actually I've stored my pic in public folder, but this worked for me: background-image: url("/background.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

Actually what worked for me was:
`background-image: url("/background.jpg");`
(picture stored in public folder and I'm using Vite).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think css can compile laravel code (I dstand to be corrected), my image is stored in the public folder accessed it with normal file path:

background-image: url("/public/body-background.jpg");

[image]